# How can I use a full-text search on a jsonb column with Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, json

So i have a `jsonb` column that has entries like this: https://pastebin.com/LxJ8rKk4

Is there any way to implement a full-text search on the entire jsonb column?

Answer (score 24):

## PostgreSQL 10+

PostgreSQL 10 [introduces Full Text Search on JSONB](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-textsearch.html)

```
CREATE INDEX ON table
   USING gin ( to_tsvector('english',jsondata) );
```

The new FTS indexing on JSON works with phrase search and skips over both the JSON-markup and keys.

Comment: I used this, but it doesn't appear to use the index when I try to search. Even with `to_tsvector('english', jsoncol) @@ to_tsquery('abc')`.

Comment: see answer below for postgresql 11+

Answer (score 9):

## PostgreSQL 11+

You can create a GiST or GIN index on jsonb columns with `jsonb_to_tsvector('<language>', <jsonb_column>, <filter>)` (or json columns with `json_to_tsvector`)

The filter can be any combination of `'["string", "numeric", "boolean", "key", "all"]'`. The first three are in regards to what kinds of values you want to include, while `"key"` includes all keys.

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  titles jsonb, 
  titles_tsvector tsvector generated always as(  
   jsonb_to_tsvector('english', titles, '["string"]')
  ) stored
)
```

See [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/functions-textsearch.html) and search for "jsonb_to_tsvector" (v13+) or "json(b)_to_tsvector" (v11, v12)

Comment: This works, but important note: **Do not put quotes around the column name in argument 2**. Postgres will just give the unclear error "invalid input syntax for type json", without any further information. Took me a few minutes to realize what was wrong.

Comment: Full example: `CREATE TABLE "testTable" (titles jsonb, titles_tsvector tsvector generated always as (jsonb_to_tsvector('english', titles, '["string"]')) stored);`

Answer (score 4):

You can, although whether that's practical is not so clear:

```
CREATE TABLE t
(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    the_data jsonb
) ;

CREATE INDEX idx_t_the_data_full_text 
    ON t 
    USING gist ( (to_tsvector('English', the_data::text))) ;
```

And then query it with:

```
SELECT
    the_data
FROM
    t
WHERE
    to_tsvector('English', the_data::text) @@ plainto_tsquery('English', 'Action') ;
```

Note that this will *also* find all your object *keys*, not only the *values*. And you'll be limited to how much text

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=a7f0e4dcf8e1a8ba98ccdcc574ebb7e6)*